# Firebase Authentication Force User To Set Password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to create a environment where admin will create a user inside firebase. Basically user will give email while giving order and if user is not in database than i need to create a account for him/her. So at that time i want to force first time to set password.

Comment: What platform is this for? Language? You need to be much more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can create user using the Firebase Admin SDK on Cloud Functions for Firebase.

See

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#create-user
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.CreateRequest.html
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Like this.

```
    admin.auth().createUser({
        uid: "uid",
        displayName: "displayName",
        photoURL: "photoURL",
        email: "email",
        emailVerified: true,
        password: "password"
    });
```

And see Cloud Functions many samples

- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/6c284a689c484ac4395fde1a8e8d6c2731705b55/spotify-auth/functions/index.js
- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples